# What are some unsupervised clustering methods that are fairly easy to explain and scale well?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining

I have been tasked to identify some clusters in some data and then match these with real world counterparts to find the accuracy. To give a contrived example, say I have some data about profiles for vehicles like cars, buses and trains. I want to be able to identify these  from an unlabelled dataset of mostly numerical data using clustering techniques that ideally scale well, and aren’t too “black box” i.e. easy to explain to non-technical audiences.

I’ve thought about using kmeans and dbscan. Kmeans is fairly easy to explain but I need to choose the number of clusters as opposed to dbscan. However, both are fairly computationally intensive, and I’m looking to implement something that works real time after say an API call.

What’s the best way of going about this?

Comment: For the record "real time" is technically impossible unless there's a bound on the data size: the best you can hope for is proportional to the size of the data.